# Loading Ion auth controller inside blog controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am building a blog application. I have a blog controller that is the main. In a sidebar I loaded "Ion Auth Library" login template from views. But it returns this:

```
    Fatal error: Call to undefined function form_open() in C:\xampp\htdocs    \code\application   \views\auth\login.php on line 9
```

So, how do I load auth.php controller inside blog.php controller? Should I copy and paster auth controller inside blog controller, or is there another way to do it?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Since this sounds like a custom blog app you are building, I think it would be difficult for anyone to provide guidance without being provided with some context as to how your application is actually structured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you haven't loaded the form helper.  In your constructor for the blog controller put this:

```
$this->load->helper('form');
```

You can read up on how the function form_open() and the form helper work here:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Comment: No you didn understand. It is nt working because form is opened inside blog controller and cant access auth controller. I want to load auth controller inside blog controller so a form in a sidebar will work

Comment: The error you displayed is related to the form helper, you're right that i misread the error since it originates from the auth view.  I feel that you may be misusing your auth framework somehow if you need to call controller functions from another controller.  However to resolve this particular error that you displayed you simply need to load the form helper in whichever controller calls views/auth/login.php

Comment: Let Me put it this way. I want a login form in a sidebar in a blog which is a home controller. And the login form is from Ion_auth how do i do that? Do you get it?

Comment: Thanks to you all. What if I copy auth controller inside blog controller, so form_open('blog/login') instead of form(auth/login